# Download queue with option to remove or add itens in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, memory, download, queue

I want to create a download queue to make some requests in background.

I have a tableView, and when a click in a cell, one download start to show any detail.
I want to start download when I'm still in tableView and dind't click in any cell.
So, I want to start downloads before user click, to make things faster.

For example, if I have 7 cells with theirs requests (when clicked). But I want to antecipate this and with a queue start download of first cell, and after, second, etc...

And if a clicked in fifth cell, I put this download in top of queue.

I search about this, but GCD didn`t apply for what I want.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I want one download per time. And when user click, make this download the first and pause the other.

Comment: So, you want all data to be downloaded when the view controller appears, and when a cell is tapped, that item to be prioritised?

Comment: Exactly this. But I want one download per time.

Comment: I would make an array with all the urls then download one by one, and if the cell is tapped, if the item is already downloaded just inform the user about that, and if not, download the item and remove it from the array so that it won't be downloaded twice.

Comment: `NSOperationQueue` can help you with that, you can prioritize operations there, also pause or cancel them on the go.

Comment: I don't think you need anything as sophisticated as GCD queues or NSOperationQueues. You just need a simple queue, using an array is probably the simplest approach as Dimitrie suggested.  You are only executing one download at a time, so the queue is just to record which file should be downloaded next.